Installing Java 21 (JRE) on Debian 12 without sid
I'm trying to install the JRE of Java 21 in my Debian 12 headless machine, for Minecraft server purposes.
Unfortunately i saw that the packages of 21 aren't available in stable repositories, only on sid (unstable). I don't want to add the whole sid repository to avoid instability and since the only package i want is this one.
So, is there any way to install Java 21 using either apt or a .deb file - without resorting to unpack a .tar.gz?
